Is this variable upper bound function differentiable at x=0?
Consider the following function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x} & x\neq 0\\ 0 &x=0 \end{cases} $$
Then question is if the function $\int_{-1}^{x}f\left( t \right)dt$ differentiable at $x=0$?
I tried to use $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{F\left( x \right)-F\left( 0 \right)}{x}$,
and Let $F\left( x \right)=\int_{-1}^{x}f\left( t \right)dt=x^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x}+\sin1$ ,
but I had trouble figuring out what $F(0)$ is? Is $F(0)=0$?

$F(x)=x^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x}+\sin1$ is valid for all $-1<x<0$. Integration is a continuous function of the upper bound, i.e. $F\left( x \right)=\int_{-1}^{x}f\left( t \right)dt$ is a continuous function of $x$. Then $F(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} F(x)$.

thank you Asigan!
